# good way to match two vectors when order is relevant

Tags: matlab, vector, match, nearest-neighbor

I have two vectors `(v1,v2)` containing coordinates. Theoretically, these vectors should have the same length, and matching pairs `(v1(1)~v2(1), ... v1(n)~v2(n))`. however, in reality, sometimes data points are missing in either of the vectors. so I could have to skip 3 lines in v1, or 1 line in v2, etc. if we have 'used' `v2(20)` in a match, the next possible index is greater than 20.

How can I find the correct matching of the two?

I thought about calculating distances (because the coordinates should be approximately equal) ... but I'm not sure how to determine the best match.
and this approach does not seem too elegant to me. any elegant suggestions? 
I tried k-nearest neighbours, which only works in part because there is no restriction on order and I have duplicates in my vectors.

I'm using MATLAB, maybe there already exists a useful function?

```
v1                 v2
   0   100 (a)         100  -50
 150  -220 (b)        -10    90 (a)
-280  -200 (c)        -20    100
-330   330             160  -200 (b)
 300   220 (d)        -240  -200 (c)
 350   400 (e)         320   250 (d)
-100  -300 (f)         320   250
-150  -250             320   380 (e)
   0  -250 (g)        -110  -320 (f)
   0  -100             0    -250 (g)
```

I wrote letters next to correct matches

okay, I think the following should work, will implement tomorrow. still open to suggestions.:

```
while not found
see if v1(i) matches v2(i+a)
if it doesn't, swap v1 and v2 and increase a, comparing from a=0 upto a=x
```

Comment: Create [`mcve`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could tell us the actual problem you're trying to solve, rather than a specific operation you want to do.  There may be a much better way to do the whole thing.  For that matter, how do you define a "missing data"? Your example has no missing values.

Comment: by missing data I mean missing matches. the problem is as follows: there are targets on a screen that should be clicked. the target positions are saved in v1. the actual clicks are saved in v2. so sometimes, the subject forgets to click or clicks in a wrong place, etc, so the rows are not identical to v1 and I need to determine which row in v2 belongs to which row in v1. clearer now?

Comment: Ok, then, you need to rewrite your GUI so that an invalid click location, or a missing click,  brings up a warning dialog and forces the user to do it right. Otherwise you're making the dangerous assumption that you've correctly re-matched data in the presence of multiple user errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope the following help you:

It seems like you need to compute the Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) between the two sequences X and Y. DTW will find the minimum-error warping, i.e. a path that matches each point of X with one point of Y.

There are many DTW tutorials (check for pdfs, youtube videos) and [matlab code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43156-dynamic-time-warping--dtw-) that you can check.

Depending on your problem, you may need to change a few things in DTW, in order to handle the missing data in the way it suits best your application.

Check also the [Edit Distance](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/med.pdf), it uses similar principles as DTW and may give you a better idea of how sequences are matched.

Good luck!